# Split PHP Variable in to array

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

A php variable contains

```
$string = "256 Engineering Maths-I 21 -1 21 F";
```

printing

```
$string
```

gives output

```
256 Engineering Maths-I 21 -1 21 F
```

this variable should split in to

```
$n[0] = "256";
$n[1] = "Engineering Maths-I";
$n[2] = "21";
$n[3] = "-1";
$n[4] = "21";
$n[5] = "F";
```

I have tried with

```
$n = explode(" ", $string);
```

but it is splitting in to 2 parts

Please help me

Comment: How is the script supposed to know that `Engineering Maths-I` should be kept together? What's the rule?

Comment: @Barmar Think it's probably tab separated and browser is collapsing the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking at is a tab separated string

Do this

```
$n = explode("\t", $string);
```

**UPDATE** 
The answer was that the text was delimited by a newline. so

```
$n = explode("\n", $string);
```

The browser's behavior of collapsing whitespace to a single space was masking what was really happening.

Comment: THankyou so much for ur hint sir, actually it is \n nd I will accept ur answer in 9 mins, please edit ur answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to split on whitespace:

```
$n = preg_split('/\s+/', $string);
```

Comment: That will split the Engineering and Maths-I... which is not what OP wants