# How convert text to array in php?

Tags: php

I have some data like: oil dispenser, oil container, oil spray bottle, oil Bottle
And I want it to become: ["oil dispenser", "oil container", "oil spray bottle", "oil Bottle"]
How can I convert a string into an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array to String PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split PHP Variable in to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755910/split-php-variable-in-to-array)

Comment: @Nick yep that's implode()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Solution**

```
$string = 'oil dispenser, oil container, oil spray bottle, oil Bottle';

$array = array_map('trim', explode(',', $string));

var_dump($array);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "oil dispenser"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "oil container"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "oil spray bottle"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "oil Bottle"
}
```